# Select distinct [user role] with higher view, write, execute permission

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My Users have [Roles] with View|Edit|Execute permission (all are [bit] columns).
Each User can also belong to [UserGroup] witch has its own Roles defined.

**What I have:**

After union both result's, I get duplicated roles from each table.

[image: Duplicated Roles]

```
declare @Roles TABLE
(
  RoleId int, 
  RoleCode nvarchar(max),
  CanView bit,
  CanEdit bit,
  CanExecute bit
)

insert into @Roles (RoleId, RoleCode, CanView, CanEdit, CanExecute)
select t.RoleId, t.RoleCode, t.CanView, t.CanEdit, t.CanExecute from (

    -- Get User Roles
    select R.Id as 'RoleId', R.CodeName as 'RoleCode', U.CanView, U.CanEdit, U.CanExecute from TM.dbo.UserRoles U
    left join TM.dbo.Roles R on U.RoleId = R.Id
    where U.UserId = @UserId

    union

    -- Get User Group Roles
    select R.Id as 'RoleId', R.CodeName as 'RoleCode', GR.CanView, GR.CanEdit, GR.CanExecute from TM.dbo.Roles R
    inner join TM.dbo.GroupRoles GR on R.Id = GR.RoleId
    inner join TM.dbo.UserGroups UG on GR.GroupId = UG.GroupId
    where UG.UserId = @UserId

) as t

select * from @Roles
```

**Expected Result:**

The result should contain 1 row for each Role but have View|Edit|Execute permission set to the one with higher permission.

[image: Expected Roles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with a `MAX` having converted the `BIT` to `INT` beforehand.

```
insert into @Roles (RoleId, RoleCode, CanView, CanEdit, CanExecute)
select 
    t.RoleId, 
    t.RoleCode, 
    CanView = MAX(CONVERT(INT, t.CanView)), 
    CanEdit = MAX(CONVERT(INT, t.CanEdit)), 
    CanExecute = MAX(CONVERT(INT, t.CanExecute))
from (

        -- Get User Roles
        select R.Id as 'RoleId', R.CodeName as 'RoleCode', U.CanView, U.CanEdit, U.CanExecute from TM.dbo.UserRoles U
        left join TM.dbo.Roles R on U.RoleId = R.Id
        where U.UserId = @UserId

        union

        -- Get User Group Roles
        select R.Id as 'RoleId', R.CodeName as 'RoleCode', GR.CanView, GR.CanEdit, GR.CanExecute from TM.dbo.Roles R
        inner join TM.dbo.GroupRoles GR on R.Id = GR.RoleId
        inner join TM.dbo.UserGroups UG on GR.GroupId = UG.GroupId
        where UG.UserId = @UserId

    ) as t
GROUP BY
    t.RoleId,
    T.RoleCode
```

Comment: Huh, haven't tested it. But is a MAX of a bit not possible without a CAST to INT ?

Comment: That's right, there's a convesion to INT written there.

Comment: Ok, I guess it is like that. `declare @T table (id int primary key identity(1,1), col int, bitcol bit);
insert into @T (col, bitcol) values (1,0),(1,1);
select col, MAX(bitcol) as max_bitcol
from @T
group by col`  returns the error "Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.".

Comment: @EzLo thank you! It works like a charm. Regarding bit data type, I changed them to tinyint.